# Sphere-Sphere intersection c#, 3D coordinates of collision points

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, coordinates, collision-detection, intersection

Ive had a look over numerous 3D sphere-sphere intersection questions and unfortunately they are either too far ahead of my ability to comprehend or not tailored to what I am looking for.

This is within the Unity Game Engine and using c#

I have managed to get this piece of code working:

```
public void calculatePoints_H(Vector3 c1p, Vector3 c2p, float c1r, float c2r, out Vector3 startLine, out Vector3 endLine)
{
    //c1p = circle one position
    //c1r = circle one radius

    Vector3 P0 = c1p;
    Vector3 P1 = c2p;

    float d,a,h;


    d = Vector3.Distance(P0,P1);

    a = (c1r*c1r - c2r*c2r + d*d)/(2*d);

    h = Mathf.Sqrt(c1r*c1r - a*a);


    Vector3 P2 = (P1 - P0);
            P2 = (P2 * (a/d));
            P2 = (P2 + P0);

    float x3,y3,x4,y4 = 0;

    x3 = P2.x + h*(P1.y - P0.y)/d;
    y3 = P2.y - h*(P1.x - P0.x)/d;

    x4 = P2.x - h*(P1.y - P0.y)/d;
    y4 = P2.y + h*(P1.x - P0.x)/d;;

    //draw visual to screen (unity 3D engine)
    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(x3,0,y3), new Vector3(x4,0,y4),Color.green);

    //out parameters for a line renderer
    startLine = new Vector3(x3,0,y3);
    endLine = new Vector3(x4,0,y4);


}
```

Currently this code allows me to calculate the two points on the x and z axis of two spheres intersecting and then draw a line.

What I want to achieve is a xyz intersection point so I can also add height (y vector 3 value) into the method so I can have a sphere intersect another from any direction/height

Could someone help me understand the way to go around doing this please, my brains a little fried and I fear its a simple solution I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spheres are nice because you know the intersection point, if they are touching, is some distance along a vector **AB** from **SphereA** center to **SphereB** center.  That distance is a function of sphere radius:

```
float dA = SphereA.radius / AB.magnitude // % distance along AB starting from SphereA
```

From there you calculate how far along **AB** your intersection point is:

```
Vector3 p = SphereA.position + AB * dA; // eq: p`= p + direction * time
```

Example (uses Unity's built-in sphere prefab):

```
bool Intersect(out Vector3 ip, float threshold=0.1f){
    // vector from sphere 1 -> sphere 2
    Vector3 ab = Sphere2.transform.position - Sphere1.transform.position;

    // Calculate radius from Unity built-in sphere.
    // Unity spheres are unit spheres (diameter = 1)
    // So diameter = scale, thus radius = scale / 2.0f.
    // **Presumes uniform scaling.
    float r1 = Sphere1.transform.localScale.x / 2.0f;
    float r2 = Sphere2.transform.localScale.x / 2.0f;

    // When spheres are too close or too far apart, ignore intersection.
    float diff = Mathf.Abs(r2 + r1 - ab.magnitude);
    if( diff >= threshold) {
        ip = Vector3.zero;
        return false;
    }
    // Intersection is the distance along the vector between
    // the 2 spheres as a function of the sphere's radius.
    ip = Sphere1.transform.position + ab * r1/ab.magnitude;
    return true;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
void FixedUpdate(){
    Vector3 p; //will hold intersection point if one is found
    if(Intersect(out p,0.1f)){
        IntersectionPoint.transform.position = p;
        IntersectionPoint.renderer.enabled = true;
    } else {
        IntersectionPoint.renderer.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

This will only return a single intersection point.  Multiple intersection points, like when the spheres overlap, is a different problem to tackle.

Comment: Thank you for that. How much of a problem would it be to modify the example so that it made use of triangulation and the intersection point of 3 spheres?

Comment: @Sean "...made use of triangulation"  Do you mean mesh on mesh collisions?  As for 3 spheres, it can be adapted but not trivially. I'll try and track down an old snippet I have that should suffice.

Comment: well at the moment I have some code that displays when two, or three, spheres intersect each other. However, this only happens in the X and Z plane. What I'm really wanting, and what you showed me to do with one sphere, is to also workout at what height do each of the spheres intersect each other.