# Represent the plane of intersection of two spheres in Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry, wolfram-mathematica

I have two spheres in unity on an xyz plane. They each have known centers and radii. I know to find the plane of intersection of two spheres, you subtract each equation. Ex:

Sphere 1: `4 = (x-1)^2 + y^2 + z^2`
Sphere 2: `1 = (x+1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2`
Plane of intersection: `0=-4x + 2y + 2z - 5`

[image]

How do I turn the plane of intersection defined by `0=-4x + 2y + 2z - 5` into an actual plane in Unity? My math knowledge is very limited. Any help would be much appreciated.

*Thank you for reading*

Comment: [You just need](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane-ctor.html) an inpoint, which you can trivially compute by setting any two of the three dimensions to zero and solving your equation (e.g. x=0, y=0 gives z=5/2), and the plane's normal, which you also have because it's the vector between the sphere centers, normalized.

Comment: to extend on @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans comment: In Unity specific you can use a simpler approach. The normal as said stays the same `sphere2.position - sphere1.position` ... as `inPoint` you can simply use the center of the intersection which is purely based on the two sphere radius see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19916880/sphere-sphere-intersection-c-3d-coordinates-of-collision-points

Comment: if by "actual plane" you rather meant a 3D object you can basically use the same and simply assign (e.g. for a Quad primitive) `quad.position = centerOfIntersection; quad.rotation = Quaternion.LookDirection(sphereCenterNormal); quad.localScale = Vector3.one * desiredSize;`